# onNavigationItemSelected is not called when the selected menu item is same

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, bottomnavigationview

I have a simple `BottomNavigationView` with two menu items (Home Fragment, Settings Fragment) in an activity.

I have implemented `onNavigationItemSelectedListener` and `onNavigationItemSelected`.

Also `bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)`;

App page lands on the Home Fragment.

`onNavigationItemSelected` is being called when I switch between menu items but When I first launch the app and tap on the same menu Item i.e. Home Fragment, `onNavigationItemSelected` is not being called.

I would need to show a toast whenever the user clicks on the home page when user is already in home page but `onNavigationItemSelected` event is not triggered.

Comment: There is a callback interface for that, but it's been modified a bit recently. Have a look here: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/BottomNavigationView#setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener(com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemReselectedListener).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mike M mentioned,

[setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/BottomNavigationView#setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener(com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemReselectedListener)) did the trick.

Answer (score -1):

First of all we do this in the MainActivity

```
@Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int v = item.getItemId();
        if(v==R.id.home)
        {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");
            Fragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment).commit();
        }
        else if (v==R.id.dash_board)
        {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Dashboard");
            Fragment fragment = new DashboardFragment();
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment).commit();
        }
   return true;
    }
};
```

[This is a example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8Aty.gif)
If you want to know in detail then [click here](https://codinghubexpress.blogspot.com/2022/03/bottomnavigationview-android-example.html)

Comment: Please take a look at the question Looking for an event when the same item is reselected.

Comment: This doesn't answers the question asked by OP. Please edit it.